# How to stub gettextfile method in fake_ftp gem?

Tags: ruby, ftp, mocking

I'm using [fake_ftp](https://github.com/livinginthepast/fake_ftp) gem.

I need the `fake_ftp` to return file by using method `gettextfile` and can't find any mention about it in readme file.

How to make `fake_ftp` gem to return some file on downloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monkey-patch FakeFTP::Server or fork it and add functionality you want.

According to [Net::FTP#gettextfile API](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-gettextfile), it can be implemented in this way:

```
class FakeFTP::Server
  def gettextfile(remotefile, localfile = nil)
    content = file(remotefile).data
    File.open(localfile, "w+"){|f| f << content} if localfile
    yield(content) if block_given?
  end
end
```